# What is $A$ in the definition of atlas?

Tags: differential-geometry

The definition of atlas I encountered is

> An atlas for $M$ is a family {$\varphi_\alpha: U_\alpha \rightarrow U_\alpha^\prime: \alpha \in A $} of charts such that {$U_\alpha: \alpha \in A$} is an open cover of $M$.

Intuitively, I guess it is just the index set, a place where holds all the names of the subsets. But this is rather ungrounded.

The entry on wikipedia used $\alpha$ without define which set it belongs to, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_%28topology%29.

And I checked Clifford Taubes' *Differential Geometry*, he defined chart without mentioning atlas altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. $A$ is just an index set. It merely gives a label to each chart.

Note that a chart is an element of an atlas; therefore to define a chart you won't mention an atlas. It's the other way around: an atlas is a special collection of charts.

Taubes's book defines an atlas without an indexing set, but the definition he gives is equivalent. This will just change some notation. For example
$$\bigcup_{\alpha \in A} U_\alpha$$
would be written
$$\bigcup_{(U, \varphi) \in \mathcal{U}} U$$
in Taubes's book.

Answer (score 2):

It is as you've guessed. Where Wikipedia says $\bigcup U_\alpha$, it means the union over all $\alpha \in A$, or just "all alpha" where the universe is implicitly the whole index set, whatever that is. Since the index set isn't otherwise used, it's often considered extraneous in mathematical writing.